# RSA Encryption: Java code to PHP code

Tags: java, php, rsa

I'm trying to implement RSA Encryption in both Java and PHP, but I can't seem to get PHP to output the same  Encrypted Result with Java.

Java Code

```
public static String sign(byte[] data,String privateKey)throws Exception{
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(privateKey);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

    //KEY_ALGORTHM="RSA";
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORTHM);
    PrivateKey privateKey2 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec);

    //SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM="SHA1WithRSA"
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
    signature.initSign(privateKey2);
    signature.update(data);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(signature.sign());
}
```

PHP Code

```
public function sign( string $data,string $privateKey){
      openssl_private_encrypt($data,$encrypted,$privateKey);
      return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

Can someone help me to translate it to PHP Code ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated o.O

Comment: Which PHP code did you write so far?

Comment: @Med hi,Med,I have added the PHP code

Comment: From the [openssl_private_encrypt man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) have you played around with the `$padding` arg? It defaults too `OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING` but you may want `OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

In Java Code,it's SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM is 'SHA1WithRSA'

so,In PHP Code

```
public function sign( string $data,string $privateKey){
  openssl_sign($data,$sign,$privateKeyString,OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
  return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

Comment: Good stuff please mark this as the answer so the topic can be closed =)

Comment: @IsThisJavascript ok，but SO said 2 days later then I can  mark my answer as the topic's answer:)